# Showing progressing progressbar while compressing android

Tags: android, progressdialog, compression

I created an app in android that enables the user to compress/decompress a file. I need to show a `ProgressDialog` to show the progress while compressing/decompressing a file. I know how to do the `ProgressDialog`, but I do not know how will I display the current progress or what will I put inside the `publishProgress(code here)`. My problem is similar to this one:

[Download a file with Android, and showing the progress in a ProgressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog)

But the link refers for downloading a file but what I need is for compressing/decompressing file. Thanks!

Comment: you can start showing your dialog in PreExecution of Async task with ProgressDialog.show() and in doInBackground you can do your compressing and Dismiss your dialog in PostExecution.

Comment: @AndroidCoader I think he is asking about how to use a bar style ProgressBar and specifically how to determine what percentage complete the compression/decompression is so that that value can be set to the progress bar.

Comment: Thanks Tim. Sorry I can't post my codes here its confidential. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Did you get the solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom `AsyncTask` class.  aka `private class MySync extends AsyncTask {`

1. `onPreExecute()` , set up the `ProgressDialog`, set your max value `setMax()`
2. `doInBackGround(...)` , compress/decompress, set the current progress `setProgress()`
3. `onPostExecute()` , end the ProgressDialog (.dismiss())

I would need to see your code to determine a way to quantify your progress.